# Is there a common (not any) type in typescript for [] and LinkedList<>/Dictionary<>

Tags: json, collections, typescript

We have to copy objects across between a web worker and the main application. We have set up a system where, for each class that is copied across, we define an interface and then a class that implements the interface.

This works great because the JSON that is copied across can be cast to the interface and then the properties can be assigned. It's not critical to have the class implement the interface, but it's clean and probably will reduce bugs.

But we have a problem. We use the [typescript-collections](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections) class. So my class will have:

```
export class DocHeader {

    public format:DocumentFormat;
    public fonts : collections.LinkedList<fonts.FontAttributes>;
    public styles : collections.Dictionary<string, styles.Style>;
```

But the JSON is an array and therefore will be:

```
export interface IDocHeader {

    format:DocumentFormat;
    fonts : fonts.FontAttributes[];
    styles : styles.Style[];
}
```

I know the answer is probably "no, not possible." But I figure it never hurts to ask. Is there some type (and not any) like IEnumerable at least that I can use in the interface that matches both uses?

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for? `Dictionary<string, Style>` and `Style[]` have literally nothing in common. You can't do anything with one that you could also do with the other.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh - correct. In C# I could make this work using IEnumerable, even with a Dictionary. But I think in javascript, since the JSON by definition is an array, there's no way.

Comment: The `Dictionary` more than likely matches `any` better than it does an array. It's likely that the data is stored as an associative array inside of the `Dictionary`.

Comment: Have you considered an interface for `IDictionary<k, v>`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie - the interface is a really good idea. I think I'll try that. thanks.

Comment: Also -- you might consider not using that class at all. It doesn't do much really that can't be done in a few lines of TypeScript. Sometimes, embracing the platform and avoiding compat-type libraries can be liberating! :)

Comment: @WiredPrairie - I need to make lookup calls into the Dictionary a lot. Can it really be almost as fast using an array with typescript calls? If so, is there a url that shows how to do this so it is fast? Thanks

Comment: An associative array is based on a hash. `var d={}; d[key]=value; if(typeof d[key] === 'undefined') { /* no key */ };` To remove: `delete d[key];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON type you're looking for is an associative array:

```
export interface IDocHeader {
    format: DocumentFormat;
    fonts: fonts.FontAttributes[];
    styles: { [styleId: string]: styles.Style; };
}
```